Keyframes animation not playing on Firefox
My css animation works how I want it to on Edge and Chrome but refuses to initialize on Firefox, I've tried including both the -moz- and -keyframes- tags for the animation and keyframes properties but nothing can get it to work on the mobile or desktop version of Firefox.
I've included my animation below, any help is appreciated.


.slogan {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2.5rem);
    animation: fade 2s ease 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}


.consumer {
    transform: translateY(2.5rem);
    background:
      linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 0 100% /var(--d, 0) 1px no-repeat,
      linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 100% calc(100% - 8px) /var(--d, 0) 1px no-repeat;
    animation: underline 1s ease 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
    to {
        --d: 100%;
        background-position: 0% calc(100% - 1px), 100% calc(100% - 2px);
        transition: 1s, background-position 1s 1s;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
<div class="slogan">
    <h2>Your <span class="consumer">consumer-driven</span> web hosting service.</h2>
</div>



Edit:
This is the expected behaviour: https://imgur.com/a/SvPh9PO

It seems to be behaving the same on chrome and firefox for me. Is it working for you on firefox when you isolate the animation?

It still doesn't work for me on Firefox but will on everything else for some reason, even if I isolate it.

Proper [mre], please. Your code above uses CSS variables that don't have values set anywhere.

Updated the post again, changed the custom properties to currentColor

Still no value for --d, which you are using in your linear-gradients.

You could replace it with --a or --c if you want.. It still works in every browser but firefox

The keyframes are running fine, it's the values used by the keyframes that are different
Define from
It seems FireFox and chrome are handling the default value for --d differently. Setting a from and value for --d results in the same behavior for FireFox and Webkit.
from {
  --d: 0;
}



.slogan {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(2.5rem);
  animation: fade 2s ease 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.consumer {
  transform: translateY(2.5rem);
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 0 100% /var(--d, 0) 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 100% calc(100% - 8px) /var(--d, 0) 1px no-repeat;
  animation: underline 1s ease 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
  from {
    --d: 0
  }
  to {
    --d: 100%;
    background-position: 0% calc(100% - 1px), 100% calc(100% - 2px);
    transition: 1s, background-position 1s 1s;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<div class="slogan">
  <h2>
    Your <span class="consumer">consumer-driven</span> web hosting service.
  </h2>
</div>



Custom properties in keyframes
This is relatively new tech, generally you would want to define a @property for these.
It can set defaults and apply constraints to the custom property (--d)
@property
use a  @property declaration for the custom property that receive a value in your keyframes.
@property --d {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

This question explores the topic further.
Both browsers also fail to swap between number '0'
and percentage '0%' in the var(--d, 0) rule.
Using var(--d, 0%) will result in what I think is the intended effect.


@property --d {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0%;
}

.slogan {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(2.5rem);
  animation: fade 2s ease 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.consumer {
  --d: 0%;
  transform: translateY(2.5rem);
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 0 100% / var(--d, 0%) 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 100% calc(100% - 8px) / var(--d, 0%) 1px no-repeat;
  animation: underline 1s ease 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
  from {
    --d: 0%;
  }
  to {
    --d: 100%;
    background-position: 0% calc(100% - 1px), 100% calc(100% - 2px);
    transition: 1s, background-position 1s 1s;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<div class="slogan">
  <h2>
    Your <span class="consumer">consumer-driven</span> web hosting service.
  </h2>
</div>



From this isolated example, I would personally avoid setting that variable (--d) altogether. It seems overly complicated, though I don't know the constraints you're working under.
